# How to handle uncaught Exceptions in javascript without a try/catch-block?

Tags: javascript, exception

What i try to accomplish is to register a global handler to catch all uncaught exceptions. 
Searching the web i only managed to find people pointing out **window.onerror** but this doesn't do the trick for me. 
Apparently window.onerror only gets called upon errors and not upon exceptions.
Assume the following code:

```
    function windowError(message, url, line) {
        alert(message, url, line);
    }
    window.onerror=windowError;
    throw("uncaught");
```

The obviously uncaught exception won't trigger the windowError handler. (Using Firefox 3.6.3)

Any suggestions?

Comment: The above code works great on chrome v12. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

**Errors** are caught the same way as **exceptions** in javascript and in fact, in your example the message get's *alerted* (Firefox 3.6.3).

Comment: That is quite odd. It don't get any alert with Firefox 3.6.3.

Comment: I've tried your example on a simple html page and it does work. That's  odd that on your Firefox is not 'alerting'... Have you tried on another browser?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know you'll need try/catch blocks to make this happen. That's sort of the point, that you need to know when to handle which kinds of errors.

Comment: found this post when googling for how to catch unhandeled javascript exceptions. You cant foresee all type of exceptions that will happen in a given code. window.onerror is a good way to at least display error. I have gone further and on my site i post the data in the window.onerror event to a webmethod on my server and logged the error to the app log.